# Find current IAM user that service is running as using .net SDK?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We have a service that is going to be using AWS services using the AWS SDK. We would like to log what IAM User and or Role that the service is running under so it is clear during debugging and when logging in production to clarify how security is working.

On developer machines, it's likely that the application is running using the developers keys, and the code will likely then assume a role. In production though, the service will be running on an EC2 instance which will have a role assigned to it. We would like to log how the service is running, but I could not find any reference to detecting the user and or role that code is running on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the STS [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) API call.